# Angularjs collapse button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to launch simple example of [collapse](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) but it do not work. Nothing happens when i am clicking on button "Toggle collapse". In console i have no errors. But in visual studio i have only one warning. What is wrong how to fix it?

[image]

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
@* Here  ng-app="MyApp" is used for auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application. here ng-app="MyApp" means <body> element is the owner
of AngularJS application*@
<body ng-app="MyApp">
@RenderBody()

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@* Add Angular Library Here *@
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
<script src="~/Scripts/MyApp.js"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace AngularJs2
{
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                "~/Scripts/angular-route.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
}
```

MyApp.js

```
(function () {
//Create a Module 
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);  // Will use ['ng-Route'] when we will implement routing
//Create a Controller
app.controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
});
})();
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse</button>
<hr>
<div uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
    <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't loaded the ui.bootstrap and loaded the proper files.

Try installing angular-ui using bower or npm and make sure too add ui.bootstrap as a dependency to your app (in MyApp.js, in the same way as you added ngRoute as a dependency). Add the installed library to your bundle-config (angular). Check in your console that all the required javascript files and css files are loded (

Then the uib-collapse will work.

If you don't want to do all the hazzle of adding this library to your project; you can always make your own "collapsable" (in this case) by changing the uib-collapse="collapsed" to ng-show="collapsed". Which will behave the same way for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Might you have forgotten ui.bootstrap dependency

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your module is missing these statement and make sure your javascript references are correct:

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```